# Soft for 3g modems setup

Tags: mobile-broadband, 3g, 4g

I need setup 3g internet in location with weak signal strength.

Does anybody know soft for 3g modems setup (measure signal level, frequency and etc...). I need watch RSSI in dbm, base station id and other service info. Something like MDMA (http://www.3g-modem-wiki.com/page/MDMA+%28generic%29) or My Huawei Terminal on Windows.

Comment: Software is already included in Ubuntu.

Comment: I need watch RSSI in dbm, base station id and other service info. Default Ubuntu software doesn't show this  info

Comment: Then I'm  afraid  you'll have to write  it yourself.